# DSL for enabling the Build periodically in jenkins

Tags: dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I know how to do it using polling, with

```
triggers
{
  scm("H/15 * * * *")
}
```

How do I specify the trigger to Build periodically instead?
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use `cron` to build periodically, as in:

```
triggers
{
  cron("H/15 * * * *")
}
```

This will build every 15 minutes regardless of whether there are SCM changes.